# How to serialize a double in C++ with Boost.Spirit so that the output is close to that from std streams?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I want to replace the calls to `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(d)` with a solution that:

1. Does not use locales (I suspect it to be the cause of slow-down in multi-threaded apps),
2. Preserves the same output as `lexical_cast`.

I am using a generator written in Boost.Spirit.Karma (because it is faster). But after the change the results are different, because Karma has its own way of displaying fractional parts of `double`s.

I know that to some extent one can control the `double` generator with policies, but my attempts fail. The best I can come up with is this generator customization and this test program:

```
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

template <typename Num>
struct fp_policy : karma::real_policies<Num>
{
  template <typename OutputIterator>
  static bool dot (OutputIterator& sink, Num n, unsigned /*precision*/)
  {
      if (n)
        return karma::char_inserter<>::call(sink, '.');  // generate the dot by default
      else
        return false;
  }

  static unsigned precision(Num)
  {
      return 15;
  }
};

karma::real_generator<double, fp_policy<double>> const fp_generator {};

std::string karma_to_string(double const& v)
{
    std::string ans;
    std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink {ans};
    (void)karma::generate(sink, fp_generator, v);
    return ans;
}

void test_number (double x)
{
  std::cout << "stream:        " << x << "\n";
  std::cout << "lexiical_cast: " << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(x) << "\n";
  std::cout << "spirit:        " << karma_to_string(x) << "\n";
  std::cout << "--------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  test_number(0.45359237);
  test_number(111.11);
  test_number(1.0);
  test_number(3.25);
}
```

And it gives the following output:

```
stream:        0.453592
lexiical_cast: 0.45359237000000002
spirit:        0.45359237
--------------------------------------------
stream:        111.11
lexiical_cast: 111.11
spirit:        111.109999999999999
--------------------------------------------
stream:        1
lexiical_cast: 1
spirit:        1
--------------------------------------------
stream:        3.25
lexiical_cast: 3.25
spirit:        3.25
--------------------------------------------
```

And as you can see there are obvious differences. If I go with the default generator for doubles (`karma::double_`), results still vary but in different places:

```
stream:        0.453592
lexiical_cast: 0.45359237000000002
spirit:        0.454
--------------------------------------------
stream:        111.11
lexiical_cast: 111.11
spirit:        111.11
--------------------------------------------
stream:        1
lexiical_cast: 1
spirit:        1.0
--------------------------------------------
stream:        3.25
lexiical_cast: 3.25
spirit:        3.25
--------------------------------------------
```

My question: how to configure the generator for `double`s (or if it is even possible?) so that the output is closer to stream based converters?

Comment: this seems like an XY problem. I think that in general it's a bad ideea to rely on the user-friendly representation of floating points. For serialization look into `frexp` and `ldexp` or maybe hex float format.

Comment: @bolov: maybe it is an XY. My goal is to replace `lexical_cast` with something that is faster and does not use locale, but preserves the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a generator based on `sprintf`, like I reverse-engineered here:

- [Boost's lexical_cast From double to string Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080749/boosts-lexical-cast-from-double-to-string-precision/48085309#48085309)

> That answer comes with a full test-suite to verify "lexical-cast compliance" for values including NaN, positive/negative zero and infinities.

If you want I can think up a demo. By far the simplest thing to do would seem to wrap the value in a type with overloaded output streaming operations, so that the [`boost::spirit::karma::stream` directive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/stream/stream.html) can be used.

Alternatively, you can create a custom generator type (satisfying the [concept requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/generator_concepts/generator.html)).

Comment: I actually didn't say it in my question, but my goal is to avoid a solution that is using locales (as I suspect this to be the source of slowdown in multi-threaded apps).

Comment: After the edit in your question, I'm confused. Which is it? Do you not want to use locales (1.) **or** do you want to have the same behaviour as `boost::lexical_cast` (2.)? You can't have both, as the test cases in the answer I linked clearly show. I can /imagine/ ways to resolve the conflicts, but I'd rather wait for you to clarify the requirements before I invest more time.

Comment: thank you for asking the right questions. They make me think more clearly. I want to drop `lexical_cast` because it is too slow, most probably to locales. But I cannot risk changing the behavior. You are right, locales configure the behavior, but somehow, the default locale on all Unix machines are tested were always the same. I thought that the default locale does something quite common, and that someone has already done the output identical to using the default locale. DOes that make sense?

Comment: The "default locale" will depend on the environment. If we replace _that_ with "C locale" (aka classic), that's a good constraint I think. Thinking about it